# Local networking without an existing Wi-Fi or Internet connection

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct, bonjour

I am trying to create an app that can communicate and send data between multiple nearby devices (likely around 2-6 devices at a time) without already being connected to the same network. This would function similarly to Apple's AirDrop and Nintendo's DS networking.

Compatibility between multiple operating systems is important. I would like to support the latest versions of Linux/Android/Windows at a minimum and preferably iOS/MacOS as well (if possible).

The app shouldn't interfere with an existing Wi-Fi or Internet connection if there is one, so solutions like [FlyingCarpet](https://github.com/spieglt/FlyingCarpet) (connects to a hotspot hosted by one device, disconnecting from Wi-Fi in the process) wont work.

Connecting devices should be simple; something like a permission popup is fine but the user shouldn't have to modify their settings for it to work.

### Options I've looked at

I already tried to implement this using [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/). According to [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/12885), AirDrop uses it internally. Unfortunately the documentation is outdated and P2P doesn't appear to work anymore with the C api. I also could not find any documentation for P2P in the Linux implementation, [Avahi](https://avahi.org).

Wi-Fi Direct seems like it may be an option, but I couldn't find a clear answer as to whether or not this would require some kind of authentication and pairing sequence prior to connecting.

Wi-Fi Aware/Neighbor Awareness Networking looks like it would fit well except that it seems to only be supported on select Android devices and not Linux nor Windows

OpenWirelessLink was another option I looked at, although it appears to be unmaintained since 2020